# Add stylesheet per layout

Tags: templates, css

Could anyone tell me what is the best and most efficient way to add separate style sheet only to one template? Do I have to have separate header and call it there or there is some Wordpress trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a page template, then you can do a conditional check with `is_page_template()` and includethe CSS in the header with `wp_enqueue_syle()`. Something like this:

```
function themename_include_page_specific_css() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-name.php' ) :
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'themename_page_specific_css',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/page-specific-style.css'
        );
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_include_page_specific_css' );
```

Keep in mind, that the parameter you pass to `is_page_template()` must be the name of the template including the path relative to the directory of the theme. Meaning that if your template is in `templates` folder you should write it like:

`is_page_template( 'templates/template-name.php' )`

This will also work with other [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) like `is_page()`, `is_single()`, and similar.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!